# How to do Authentication with Node.js and MEAN stack?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am currently working on a text based game with a small team of developers. The game requires login and we are using the MEAN (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node) Stack for the application codebase, however i am stuck on authentication, as a rails developer i am used to being able to drop in a gem and use the helpers available.

has anybody has any experience with MEAN and Authentication?

Comment: there's easyauth for fb, twitter etc login: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth

Answer (score 34, accepted):

the MEAN stack by linnovate uses [Passport.js](http://passportjs.org) for its authentication. Passport uses different strategies for authentication. One of these strategies is a username and password pair, which they call *LocalStrategy*.

Here is one of the samples from the Passportjs-Local Github [Examples Page](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/wiki/Examples)

**Step 1: Require Passport**

First you require the module after doing npm install passport

```
var passport = require('passport');
```

**Step 2: Configure 'Verify' Function**

Use the LocalStrategy within Passport. Strategies in passport require a `verify` function, which accept credentials (in this case, a username and password), and invoke a callback with a user object.  In the real world, this would query a database; however, in this example we are using a baked-in set of users.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {

  // Find the user by username.  If there is no user with the given
  // username, or the password is not correct, set the user to `false` to
  // indicate failure and set a flash message.  Otherwise, return the
  // authenticated `user`.

  findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { 
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); 
      }
      if (user.password != password) { 
          return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' }); 
      }
        return done(null, user);
      })
    });
  }
));
```

**Step 3: Initialize Passport on app**

You need to tell Express that you will be using passport and that it will be managing sessions for you. This is done by using the app.use() during app configuration.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**Step 4: Configure Middleware on the login URI**

Next we need to create a method that will accept when a user tries to login to the app using by POST-ing to a specific URI. It will look like this.

```
// POST /login
//   Use passport.authenticate() as route middleware to authenticate the
//   request.  If authentication fails, the user will be redirected back to the
//   login page.  Otherwise, the primary route function function will be called,
//   which, in this example, will redirect the user to the home page.
//
//   curl -v -d "username=bob&password=secret" http://127.0.0.1:3000/login
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

**Step 5: Set up Sessions**
You may have to create your own serialization for User objects that are being stored in the sessions. That is done with the following

```
// Passport session setup.
//   To support persistent login sessions, Passport needs to be able to
//   serialize users into and deserialize users out of the session.  Typically,
//   this will be as simple as storing the user ID when serializing, and finding
//   the user by ID when deserializing.
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at http://meanjs.org/
They have a very solid integration of passport.js strategies.
Especally useful is the implementation of Salt and Crypto-Technies to make the integration safe. Search for Salz within the repo.

See 
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/modules/users/server/config/strategies/local.js
For serialization and deserialization.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you'd prefer a custom implementation, I recently posted a complete [MEAN Stack User Registration and Login Example](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/12/09/MEAN-Stack-User-Registration-and-Login-Example.aspx)

Here's the snippet from the user service that handles authentication:

```
function authenticate(username, password) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    usersDb.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) deferred.reject(err);

        if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.hash)) {
            // authentication successful
            deferred.resolve(jwt.sign({ sub: user._id }, config.secret));
        } else {
            // authentication failed
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Or use mean.io which has user management out of the box.

Comment: Yes - but it would be great to have a Passport package so we could `mean install passport`